# From a single row dataframe how to create a new dataframe containing list of column names and their values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Given df1**:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 15 | 100 | 68 | 96 | 86 | 35 | 48 |

**How to create df2**:

| columnName | ColumnValues |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | 45 |
| c2 | 15 |
| c3 | 100 |
| c4 | 68 |
| c5 | 96 |
| c6 | 86 |
| c7 | 35 |
| c8 | 48 |

**Question**: Using `pyspark`, if we are given dataframe `df1` (shown above), how can we create a dataframe `df2` that contains the column names of `df1` in the first column and the values of `df1` in the second second column?

**REMARKS**: Please note that `df1` will be dynamic, it will change based on the data loaded to it. As shown below, I already know how to do it if `df1` is static:

```
data = [['c1', 45], ['c2', 15], ['c3', 100]]
mycolumns = ["myCol1","myCol2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, mycolumns)
df.show()
```

For a static df1, the above code will show df2 as:

```
|myCol1|myCol2|
|---|---|
|c1|45|
|c2|15|
|c3|100|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [["java", "dbms", "python"]]
columns = ["Subject 1", "Subject 2", "Subject 3"]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

column_names = df1.columns

stacked = df1.selectExpr("stack(" + str(len(column_names)) + "," + ",".join([f"'{col}', `{col}`" for col in column_names]) + ") as (columnName, columnValue)")

df2 = stacked.selectExpr("columnName", "columnValue")
df2.show()

+----------+----------------+
|columnName|     columnValue|
+----------+----------------+
| Subject 1|            java|
| Subject 2|            dbms|
| Subject 3|          python|
+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I am getting `ParseException` at the second line `stacked = .....`. I am running the notebook in `Databricks`.

Comment: I created the `df1` using your input data and it worked for me. Can you post complete error message? Also if possible how did you create `df1`. I have also used Databricks here.

Comment: The error message: /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in selectExpr(self, *expr)
   1841         if len(expr) == 1 and isinstance(expr[0], list):
   1842             expr = expr[0]
-> 1843         jdf = self._jdf.selectExpr(self._jseq(expr))
   1844         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx) /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args) 1303   answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)`

Comment: I used this example: `data = [["java", "dbms", "python"],  ["OOPS", "SQL", "Machine Learning"]]  
columns = ["Subject 1", "Subject 2", "Subject 3"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)`

Comment: Edited my answer to support the edge case.

Comment: I've already upvoted. Could you please remove one row in the example I gave you. Otherwise, it will not be relevant to the question where I am saying as a `one row dataframe df1`. The example may confuse readers of this post since it has two rows and because of that the column names are repeated in df2. You may want to also re-write the display of df2 with 3 rows only. And I will accept the answer. Thank you for helping me.